# mySQL: check whether today date is a weekend and set to nearest weekday

Tags: mysql, date

How do I check whether today date is a weekend, and if it is, set to the nearest weekday within the SAME month? Using SQL.

**2 Scenarios:**

1. If weekend falls on 21st, then it will be set to 20th, Friday (weekday)
2. If weekend falls on 1st, then it will be set to 3rd, Monday (weekday)

Comment: Try doing some reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

It would have been nice if you included your table schema for a more tailored response, but generally what you are looking for is this:

```
select d, case when dayofweek(d) in (1,7) then 'weekend' else 'weekday' end as 'day type',
          if(dayofweek(d) in (1,7),
            if(day(d) = 1 and dayofweek(d) = 1,
               d + interval 1 day,
               if(day(d) = 1 and dayofweek(d) = 7,
                  d + interval 2 day,
                    if(dayofweek(d) = 1,
                       d + interval 1 day,
                       d - interval 1 day
                    )
               )
             ), d
           ) nearest_week_day
  from test;
```

[Here's a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9133f/3)

There may be better ways to do it - but this works. You may need to extend the query a little bit to handle Sundays (weekday = 1) that fall on the last day of the month.